# syntax error, unexpected ')', when trying to display text only on development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to display info on ip detected and stuff but only to me when in development mode.

I'm loading /app/views/layouts/_debug.html.erb in my footer:

```
<!-- Useful info on localization to debug app -->
<%= if Rails.env.development? %>
    <div id="debug_localization_tools">
      country detected by ip: <b><%= display_country_as_detected_by_ip %></b> <br/>
        country loaded by CountrySetter's set_country method induced from loaded locale: <b><%= loaded_country_locale_by_countrysetter_module %></b>
    </div>
<%= end %>
```

It's giving me an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The `if` and `end` should be using `<%`, not `<%=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code that should get outputted start with `<%=`, whether code that should *not* simply start with `<%`.

So in your code, the `if` clause (including the `end`) does not produce something you want to render, therefor go with the latter option

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <div id="debug_localization_tools">
    country detected by ip: <b><%= display_country_as_detected_by_ip %></b> <br/>
    country loaded by CountrySetters set_country method induced from loaded locale: <b><%= loaded_country_locale_by_countrysetter_module %></b>
  </div>
<% end %>
```